# Best free alternatives to Frutiger

Tags: font-recommendation

Hi i am looking for a free alternative to Frutiger that closely matches the font in the logo below. I don't think this font is Frutiger though as the doesn't quite match. would also appreciate it if you could tell me what this font was.

[image: Font sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many free "humanist" fonts pretty similar to Frutiger: Open sans,  Roboto and others. However, as others have noted, this isn't Frutiger or Helvetica. It is too extended and wrong "a" for Helvetica.

I think it is Trade Gothic Bold Extended.

Montserrat and PT Sans in google fonts are sort of close. There are few quality sans serif free fonts.

Also it's not neue haas unica (it is definitely an extended width)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make a great deal of sense. If you *know* it's Frutiger, and are willing to purchase.... shouldn't you just purchase Frutiger?

Looks to be [Helvetica Neue](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/helvetica-75-bold/) to me though.

Comment: I don't think that's Helvetica Nue, but I agree about purchasing Frutiger.  If you compare Nue's s, t and a, you will see the difference

Comment: Possibly @JohnManly -- But it's **absolutely** not Frutiger. The T and the S are dead giveaways for that. :) Helvetica Neue is *exceptionally* close. The only variations would be minutely shorter bars on the T and a slightly shorter tail on the Y. These could be attributed to foundry differences in some cases.

Comment: Yea, definitely very close.

Comment: the a seems quite different from helvetica neue and closer to fruitiger

Comment: After hours of looking I found it ! it was neue hans unica

Answer (score 0):

Some free, wide-ish free fonts that are somewhat close:

- [Global](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/global)
- [Museo Sans](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Museo-Sans)
- [Sinkin Sans](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/sinkin-sans)
- [Varela](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/varela)

None of them is an exact match but I think they'd work.